# In how many ways can $5$ awards be awarded to a class of $30$?

Tags: combinatorics

$5$ separate awards are to be presented to selected students from a class of $30$. How many different outcomes are possible if a student can receive any number of awards?

Answer (score 3):

Hint 1: for each award there are 30 possibilities

Hint 2: multiply

Comment: i see,i used to think it was complicated